# Establish Azure VPN site to site connection

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I'm trying to establish a site to site azure vpn connection with a Cisco ASA 5500 Series.

I'm using the Azure PowerShell cmdlets to diagnose a site-to-site VPN gateway connection issue, but receive the following error:

**Failure type: IKE/Authip Quick Mode Failure
Type specific info:
  Failure error code:0x00003610
    Error processing Notify payload**

In the azure portal the state always appear as connecting

[image]

What is the meaning of the diagnostic error and the possible solution or i'm missing some configuration ?

Comment: Have you tried collecting the logs as mentioned here ? http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/12/18/diagnose-azure-virtual-network-vpn-connectivity-issues-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Yes, the errors that mention in the question comes from that logs